# Search for cells in a single column containing a string and output all matching cells to new column

Tags: microsoft-excel

This sounds a lot simpler than it appears it is to achieve! I am trying to search a column for a strong CONTAINING the word "Task" and then output each of those matching cells into a new column. So, as an example:

All my data exists in column D. I would like to find all cells that contain the word "Task" and output them to column A

| Row | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Outputs** |  |  | **Task List** |
| 2 | *Task 1* |  |  | Task 1 |
| 3 | *Task 2* |  |  | Info |
| 4 | *Task 3* |  |  | Info |
| 5 |  |  |  | Info |
| 6 |  |  |  | Task 2 |
| 7 |  |  |  | Stuff |
| 8 |  |  |  | Random |
| 9 |  |  |  | Task 3 |

I have tried using:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$8,AGGREGATE(15,3,(($D$2:$D$8="Task 1")/($D$2:$D$8="Task 1")*ROW($D$2:$D$8))-ROW($D$1),ROWS($C$2:C2))),"")`

This will output "Task 1" perfectly and, if I have multiple "Task 1" in the "Task List", it will output all of them correctly under "Outputs" (column A). So I am on the right track but I want to pattern match "Task" and not "Task 1".

I suspect it requires a combination of the above and the below but it's hurting my head trying to work it out! Any help is much appreciated!

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Task",$N$9:$N$13)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the test in the following is much more straightforward and therefore easier to understand a year from now when maintaining the spreadsheet:

```
=FILTER(A1:A8,LEFT(A1:A8,4)="Task")
```

It is direct. It does not have to make assumptions about indirect results. It is also short and rather transparent.

The whole "ISNUMBER..." kind of formula piece is old school, which has nothing wrong with it per se, but for this, it wasn't even needed when the "OG" folk were calculating. It is part of a broader solution, one with less easy to work with requirements so as a benefit of the easier requirements, it needs dispensed with.

"Simpler and more transparent" is a hugely worthwhile goal:  do you want to not be promoted because no one can understand your spreadsheets and therefore none can be handed off to new subordinates? Raises often come with promotions too...

Comment: This has done the trick and way simpler than where I was going with it! I knew it wasn't a complicated thing I was trying to do! Appreciate the prompt response!!

Answer (score 0):

**This solves the issue:**

[image]

- I would like to suggest two formula. If you are using higher version
  of Excel 2021 or 365 then try this in cell AQ2.

  ```
  =FILTER(AO2:AO8,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Task *",AO2:AO8)))
  ```
- If working with older versions then you may try this array (CSE)
  formula.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($AO$2:$AO$8,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Task *",$A$O2:$A$O8)),ROW($AO$2:$AO$8)-ROW($AO$2)+1),COLUMNS($AQ1:AQ1))),"")}
  ```

**N.B.**

- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.
- Adjust cell references as needed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the **Task List range**- go to **Data**- **From Table/Range**:

[image]

2. Open **Power Query editor**- Select the **Text Filters**- select **Contains**...

[image]

3. Enter the *Task* and click **OK**:

[image]

4. Change the column name to *Output*- **Close & Loat to...**

[image]

[image]

[image]